# convert pgm 12bit/px to pgm 5

Tags: matlab, stereo-3d, pgm, disparity-mapping

I'm generating a disparity map using pgm files, the file type is 12bit/px.

I faced an error, it says "wrong magic number, only P5 PGM files supported"

Is there any solution?  can I convert to PGM?

Thanks

Comment: please give a [MCVE]

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger, I want to implement stereo matching using this code : https://github.com/ivankreso/stereo-vision/blob/master/reconstruction/base/rSGM/MyImage.hpp and when I pass my images it give me error (ONLY P5 PGM files are supported)